# Can't connect to database after restoring database from backup

Tags: java, sql-server, authentication, database-restore, squirrel-sql

I restored my local developing database with a backup file made from production database with SQL Server Management Studio. I overwrited my local database on that restore.

Now I can't connect to the database with SQL Squirrel. What could have caused this and how to fix it? Thank you.

I get the error on login "Unexpected Error occurred attempting to open an SQL connection."

Stack Trace button reveals the following:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot open database "devdatabase_myname" requested by the login. The login failed. ClientConnectionId:[id]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:206)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand.awaitConnection(OpenConnectionCommand.java:132)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand.access$100(OpenConnectionCommand.java:45)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand$2.run(OpenConnectionCommand.java:115)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot open database "devdatabase_myname" requested by the login. The login failed. ClientConnectionId:[id]
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand.executeConnect(OpenConnectionCommand.java:171)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand.access$000(OpenConnectionCommand.java:45)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand$1.run(OpenConnectionCommand.java:104)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot open database "devdatabase_myname" requested by the login. The login failed. ClientConnectionId:[id]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:254)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:84)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2908)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:2234)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:41)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:2220)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1326)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.fw.sql.SQLDriverManager.getConnection(SQLDriverManager.java:133)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand.executeConnect(OpenConnectionCommand.java:167)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: Missing `GRANT`s maybe?

Comment: Have you been able to connect from within the SQL Server Management Studio. If you can't then you know that the problem is probably some changes in authentication parameters. If you can, check whether the database name, username, password, host and port match those of the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible you have an orphaned user. if your database user is not mapped correctly to the login of the same name, the server will have no way to connect you to the right database. You can see the following article for troubleshooting help

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175475%28SQL.100%29.aspx

Comment: This is correct. I had one orphaned user and was able to fix that by following instructions here: http://geekswithblogs.net/bullpit/archive/2010/04/21/user-already-exists-in-the-current-database---sql-server.aspx  Problem solved.